# Automator can't find Symbolic Links?

Tags: automator, symlink

I'm trying to create an automator workflow that starts out by finding all symbolic links in a given directory.

What's happening however is that even if I set it to return "all files", I end up with every single file *except* symbolic links.  Automator seems to be unable to see them at all.

Is there a way to get Automator to return symlinks (not aliases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this. Automator seems to returns all files/folders, whether they are symlinks or not.

1. I set up the following:

   ```
   $ mkcd testfolder
   $ mkdir originalfolder
   $ ln -s originalfolder symlinkoforiginal
   $ ls
   total 24
   drwxr-xr-x   5 grgarside  staff   170B 23 Jul 20:04 ./
   drwx------@ 11 grgarside  staff   374B 23 Jul 20:04 ../
   -rw-r--r--@  1 grgarside  staff   6.0K 23 Jul 20:04 .DS_Store
   drwxr-xr-x   2 grgarside  staff    68B 23 Jul 20:04 originalfolder/
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 grgarside  staff    50B 23 Jul 20:04 symlinkoforiginal -> /Users/grgarside/Desktop/testfolder/originalfolder
   ```
2. I ran the following Automator workflow:

   [image]

As shown in the results, both the folder and the symlink were returned.

Comment: Interesting... yes your solution does return all files, but what I was doing was using Find Finder Items to attempt to specify symlinks only, and that's what doesn't see them at all.  I may be able to work with this but do you have any idea why Find Finder Items cannot see symlinks?

Comment: @Jonathan Ah, I presume Find Finder Items uses Spotlight `mdfind` which doesn't see symlinks either.

Comment: Aha, that would make sense.  It seems that Filter Finder Items does too, in which case how on earth can I select *only* symlinks?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think that's possible without doing some shell scripting (or using a custom action if one exists).

Comment: Drat... I do have a command line that will get me what I want, will look into executing it within automator.  Thanks...